# How to check whether the user's data (username & email address) exist in database or not?

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a SQLite database inside an application. When the user register that time, I would like the system to check whether the user and the email id is already exist inside the database or not then only create a new row is the user did not register before. How to implement the checking part? Any comments will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 2):

mLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mCursor = db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM Friend where F_email='"+mUserId.getText().toString()+"' and Pass='"+mPassword.getText().toString()+"'");
            if(mCursor.getCount() > 0)
            {
                email_id = mUserId.getText().toString();
                Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        BuddyInOut.class);
                startActivity(i1);
                mUserId.setText("");
                mPassword.setText("");
            }
            else {
                // AlertDialog on invalid User Name and Password
                AlertDialog.Builder mAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Login.this);
                mAlert.setTitle("Login");
                mAlert.setMessage("Invalid Username or Password");
                mAlert.setPositiveButton("ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    }
                });
                mAlert.show();
                mUserId.setText("");
                mPassword.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```